# Linq Querying for user search

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq-to-sql, filter

I am trying to query from search box using list of data and the linq I used is:

```
data = (From k As BSPLib.ContactLib.Contact In data_org.Values Where k.stringdata Like "%" & Searchtxtbox.Text & "%" Select k.prime).ToList
```

But this is not working, I am getting no data at all.  Data_org is a dictionary so I used the values; k.stringdata contains all the data that need to be searched.  Searchtxtbox.text contains the user defined search item.

I Tried with sqlmethods through linq, but sqlmethods does not exist for me, I tried with with Imported namespace yet the code is not showing sql methods, could you please provide a workable query or just tell me where I have gone wrong.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` wildcard character won't work here, remember this is .NET code, not SQL. You need something like this instead:

```
data = (
    From k As BSPLib.ContactLib.Contact In data_org.Values 
    Where k.stringdata.Contains(Searchtxtbox.Text) Select k.prime).ToList
```

Answer (score 1):

My Visual Basic is a bit rusty so forgive me if I have the syntax wrong:
One thing you could use is Contains which will be similar to "%Searchtxtbox.Text%"
and exactly the same if it is used with a DatabaseContext.
I know it is not the same as Like but if that doesn't work than likely something else is wrong and than I would like more code.

```
data = (From k As BSPLib.ContactLib.Contact In data_org.Values Where k.stringdata.Contains(Searchtxtbox.Text) Select k.prime).ToList
```

You can additionally use `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` for `"Searchtxtbox.Text%"` and `"%Searchtxtbox.Text"`
Also would I like to suggest to puth `"%" & Searchtxtbox.Text & "%"` between Parentheses for clarification, but that's all up to you.